# Как на Wordpress сделать главную страницу статичной?

Tags: php, wordpress, css

Нужно чтобы на главной выводилась определенная страница. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здравствуйте!
Ваша проблема решается очень просто средствами **WordPress**.
Админка -> Параметры -> Чтение -> На главной странице отображать -> **Статическую страницу.**